# Preprocessor directives supported by the RIM compiler

Tags: blackberry

This isn't really clearly documented, but a shallow search reveals that RIM's **RAPC** compiler does support preprocessor statements (with some project file modification).

We've been using the simple **#ifdef**, **#else**, and **#endif** directives for quite some time now, as supporting platforms 4.1 through 4.7 with one code base is nearly impossible without them, but I began wondering recently if there are other supported directives which aren't quite as well documented; something akin to C's **#elif** for example, or even rudimentary equivalency directives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a complete listing of commands for the RAPC preprocessor.  The preprocessor's not very robust, but that's on purpose.

**//#preprocess** - Used to specify that the file should be preprocessed. It must be the first line of the file.

**//#implicit *tag*** - This needs to be on the second line of the file.  If *tag* is part of the command line, then the whole file should be compiled.  If not, then it should be excluded.

Then there's the **//#ifdef tag ... #else ... #endif** and the **//#ifndef tag ... #else ... #endif** directives that you mentioned.

Also note, there is no nesting of preprocessed blocks and no macros.

RIM Help Center Doc:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21065/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp

Comment: I can't find official confirmation but looks like predecessor support `or` logic operator. Example `//#ifdef BlackBerrySDK6.0.0 | BlackBerrySDK7.1.0`