# Using preprocessor directives in BlackBerry JDE plugin for eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, preprocessor

How to use preprocessor directives in BlackBerry JDE plugin for eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the eclipse config file (%ECLIPSE_HOME%\configuration\config.ini) make sure the following line exists.

```
osgi.framework.extensions=net.rim.eide.preprocessing.hook
```

With the current BlackBerry plugin (1.0.0.67) config line is added for you.  I'm not sure about older versions of the plugin.

Also, checkout this Stack Overflow question for more information on the BlackBerry preprocessor.

[Preprocessor directives supported by the RIM compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179129/preprocessor-directives-supported-by-the-rim-compiler/1189573#1189573)

Comment: Once we do this, how do we use the directives in our code? Is it similar to what Antenna provides?

Comment: Edited to show a link to another question that sheds more light. Hope it helps.