# Error Loading Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

When I try to load Eclipse (an earlier version -- 1.0.67), I get an error: "Error has occured, please check log file" as shown in this [image][1].

In the log file, the error was as displayed in this image: [errorimage][2]. What could be the problem? How can it be rectified? Please help me on this.

Error shown in log file is

!SESSION Thu Apr 21 10:33:17 IST 2011 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2011-04-21 10:33:17.431
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: net.rim.eide.preprocessing.hook
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2011-04-21 10:33:17.447
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)

Comment: If you want someone to answer, it would be nice to put the error as text into the question. Links that are behind download-walls are very cumbersome for those people, who might help you.

Comment: Ok ,Still no clue,how could it be rectified.Error in log file is

Comment: Please take the time to apply the right visual format to the error, actually it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Using preprocessor directives in BlackBerry JDE plugin for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383277/using-preprocessor-directives-in-blackberry-jde-plugin-for-eclipse/1394246#1394246) first and if the problem persists [Eclipse Blackberry Preprocessor Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336627/eclipse-blackberry-preprocessor-not-working).

HTH

Comment: Sorry for my incovenient way of posting,i just got thr' posts that you pointed,Thing is that i copied the eclipse folder from someone and i am trying to use it.I checked out the Configurations files whether it contains "osgi.framework.extensions=net.rim.ejde.preprocessing.hook" or not,it is already there,I am not able to open the eclipse file itself.

Comment: Finally it worked somehow,in the configuration file of the configuration folder of eclipse,it should be like this "osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.2.R34x_v20080826-1230.jar",but it was showing this path within some other folder,so i rechanged.It worked.Still unclear of how it worked.