# Best way to organize a BlackBerry project in Eclipse (for non-touch and touch versions of the project)?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, eclipse-plugin

I have a small Java ME project (a game) that I'd like to port to BlackBerry, where I don't have any experience yet. I have identified 2 categories of devices that I would like to support, based on whether or not they support touch:
1. 320x240 and 480x360 (non-touch)
2. 360x480 (touch)

For the non-touch devices, the changes would be minimal (I will only re-map the keys to control the game), but with touch devices it seems tricky. I assume I will have to have 2 different code bases, since pre-4.7 devices didn't have touch API, and am looking for a way to minimize the amount of code I have to write. Ideally I would like to have only 1 project (is that possible)? Any suggestions on how to organize this project would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, if you're trying to support pre-4.7 devices your app won't work if it's using the touch API.  You can surround touch-specific code with something like

```
//#ifdef STORM
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
//#endif
```

I use Netbeans. The "STORM" definition is the name of my NB configuration, but you can define your own, etc...
Sorry to just paste links, but I don't know how to do it in Eclipse.:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Create_Workspace_Preprocessor_Directives_927626_11.jsp

And elsewhere on SO:

[Using preprocessor directives in BlackBerry JDE plugin for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383277/using-preprocessor-directives-in-blackberry-jde-plugin-for-eclipse)

Edit: I know this might seem like a NB specific answer, but the preprocessor is actually supported by the BlackBerry tools in general.

Comment: Thank you spacemanaki, for shedding some light and for useful links. I will try that and add a comment later when I figure it out.

Comment: Np, good luck. Switching to Eclipse is on my TODO list, I'll update if I get to it soon.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to have two separate builds to support both Touch and Non-Touch devices. You can implement the`TouchEvent`, `NavigationMovement`, and `KeyDown` methods in the appropriate classes to handle both interaction methods. The `TouchEvent` method would handle all touchscreen related interaction and the `NavigationMovement` and `KeyDown` methods would provide interaction with the devices that have a keyboard and a trackpad.

The Blackberry Torch has both a touchscreen and a trackpad which would even further complicate the separate build method.

Comment: Thank you redwoolf. Won't there be a problem with pre v4.7 devices that don't know the touch API at all, and I have the usings in that project? Won't the app crash on those older devices because of missing bindings? Thank you!