# Build BlackBerry Advanced UI package

Tags: blackberry

I downloaded the [BlackBerry advanced UI package](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276), but when I try to build it I get the following errors:

> Errors running builder 'BlackBerry
>   Pre-Process Builder' on project
>   'Advanced UI'.
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVM
>   cannot be cast to net.rim.ejde.A.J.M

I'm using:
- Eclipse 3.5
- Blackberry SDK 5.0.0.25
- Windows 7

Any idea on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some classes from that package use [preprocessor directives](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp).

It turns out preprocessor directives are not supported by earlier versions of the Eclipse plugin, but version 1.0.0.67 and later are configured correctly by default.   Earlier Eclipse plugin versions [can be enable preprocessing by editing the config files manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383277/using-preprocessor-directives-in-blackberry-jde-plugin-for-eclipse/1394246#1394246).

RIM also explains [how to manually edit the config file](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12793/Enable_application_preprocessing_655408_11.jsp) to enable preprocessing.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify that these links are for older plugins.   The linked SO question is over a year old, for example.   You shouldn't need to do this if you downloaded your Eclipse plugin recently.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have the wrong JRE set in your project properties. You need to set it to the BlackBerry JRE 5 or 6.

Project Properties->Java Build Path-> Libraries Tab -> Double Click JRE System Library

Select proper JRE.

Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your developing environment. Based on your error message, I think it's about your builder. Configure it in your project preferences.

Answer (score 0):

this was fixing it in my case.. add it to config.ini

```
osgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.mtj.core.hooks,net.rim.ejde
```