# Can't I get my app to work with click and touch (within same project)?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

i have developed an application that will basically run on all versions of the blackberry unit (ver 4.5 and above). however, i have noticed that navigationClick() is not consumed with a touch blackberry. i know that i have to use touchEvent method instead, however, my eclipse project is set up to use jde 4.5. so is there any way of just including the classes necessary for touch events inside my eclipse project? most of our customers are still using phones with 4.5 or 4.6. so setting up the project to use jde 4.7 as the foundation is out of the question.

i know that eclipse doesn't like packaging a project with 2 different jde versions configured for the same application (because of contentions).

how does everyone else roll out an application that is compatible with ALL versions (including those with the touch)? or do you guys roll out different versions of the same app (one to support click and the other to support touch)?

any help would greatly be appreciated.

thank you so much in advance.

ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have several applications for the BlackBerry, and the ones that are compatible with touch-screen RIM devices have two versions: the Standard edition, which supports RIM OS 4.1+ and is built on that platform, and the TouchScreen edition which supports Storm, Storm2, and Torch devices, and is built with the 4.7 platform.

The code base is the same and the touch code is separated with [preprocessor statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179129/preprocessor-directives-supported-by-the-rim-compiler), but as far as I understand it, there is no way to build on a platform before 4.7 and get access to the methods introduced in 4.7.