# Making one program for 2 different versions

Tags: facebook, blackberry, version-control

i want to create 2 different versions of Blackberry program 
One which supports facebook api and the other lower version which does not supports 
I came to know that version 4.6 does'nt suppport facebook api's and the version 5.0 and above does

So , how do i achieve to make a single program for both this version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following links may be helpful:

- [Coding for Multiple Blackberry Devices - Using Preprocessor Directives in Eclipse](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/coding-for-multiple-blackberry-devices.html)
- [Preprocessor directives supported by the RIM compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179129/preprocessor-directives-supported-by-the-rim-compiler)
- [Preprocessor Directives for JDE](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Preprocessor-Directives-for-JDE/td-p/71909)
- [Specifying preprocessor directives](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21065/Specifying_preprocessor_directives_657636_11.jsp)
- [Create preprocessor directives for a workspace](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Create_Workspace_Preprocessor_Directives_927626_11.jsp)
- [Create preprocessor directives for a project](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21065/Create_project_preprocessor_directives_927627_11.jsp)